# How to find the order of $ X_k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G_k = \Bbb Z_3 × · · · × \Bbb Z_3$. 
Let$ \,\,\alpha(z_1, . . . , z_{k−1}, z_k )=(−z_1, . . . ,−z_{k−1}, z_k ) \text{ where}  \,\,z_i \in\Bbb Z_3$ for $i = 1, 2, . . . ,k$. Then $α ∈ \operatorname{Aut}(G_k )$ and $A =< \alpha>$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G_k )$ of order 2. Why is 2 the order $A$?

Now let $A$ act on $ G_k$, so $\operatorname{orbit}((z_1, . . . , z_k )) = \{(z_1, . . . , z_{k−1}, z_k ), (−z_1, . . . ,−z_{k−1}, z_k)\}$, where $z_i ∈ \Bbb Z_3$ for $i = 1, 2, . . . ,k$. Finally let $X_k$ = $G_k/A$. $|X_k|=(3^k+3)/2$ why? How to find the order  of  $ X_k$?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: $Z_3$??? or $\mathbb Z_3$??

Comment: Twice you wrote "where $\,z_i\in Z\,$" ...what is $\,Z\,$?? Or is it $\,\Bbb Z_3=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\,$ ?

Comment: Then,even stranger, you say it's easy to find $\,|X_k|,$...and then you ask how to find the order of $\,X_k\;$ ?? This is very messy...

Answer (score 2):

> why the otder $A$ is 2?

Because $\alpha^2 = \mathrm{id}$. (Notice that $\alpha$ is not just some arbitrary thing *acting* by automorphisms on $G_k$, it *is* an automorphism. So if it acts as the identity everywhere, it *is* the identity.)

> how to find the order of $X_k$?

$G_k$ has size $3^k$. The orbits in $G_k$ under the action of $A$ almost all have size $2$, except a few that have size $1$. In particular, an element of the form $(z_1, \dots, z_{k-1}, z_k)$ have orbit of size $1$ if and only if $z_1 = \dots = z_{k-1} = 0$ (why?), and there are only $3$ of these elements (why?), so there are $3^k - 3$ elements with order $2$. So $G_k/A$ has size $\dfrac{3^k - 3}{2} + \dfrac{3}{1} = \dfrac{3^k + 3}{2}$, as required.